# Mapping Entity Framework entity to dto object using select

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and I am trying to map using entities to a dto object using the following code but something is going wrong:

```
var fileUploads = _dbContext.FileUploads.Include("DocumentType").Include("Store");

if (jobSearchParams.DocumentTypeId != null)
{
    fileUploads = fileUploads.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeID == 6);
}

if (jobSearchParams.StoreId != null)
{
    fileUploads = fileUploads.Where(x => x.StoreID == jobSearchParams.StoreId);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jobSearchParams.Name))
{
    fileUploads = fileUploads.Where(d => d.Name.Contains(jobSearchParams.Name));
}

var dtos = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<JobDocumentDto>>(documents);

var cnt = fileUploads.Count(); // 1412

var fileDocuments = fileUploads.AsEnumerable().Select(d => new JobDocumentDto
{
    DocumentID = d.ID,
    StoreID = d.StoreID,
    StoreName = d.Store.Name,
    Document = Mapper.Map<DocumentDto>(d),
    DocumentName = d.Name
}).ToList();

cnt  = fileDocuments.Count; // 0
```

With the `AsEnumerable` in the expression I have 0 objects after doing the select and if I remove the `AsEnumerable` I get the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'DataManagement.DTOs.DocumentDto
>   MapDocumentDto' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.ToList()` before Select, so make it `.ToList().Select(...)...`.

> Reason: LINQ is trying to convert the entire `new JobDocumentDto {...}` statement into query form, but it can't. By running the query earlier this problem is avoided.

Also the `AsEnumerable()` may now be redundant, just try removing it.

Comment: In general Linq to Enitities won`t accept any method inside select section - because you working with the genreated by Entity Framework query not the data, only after calling ToList() or ToDictionary() you actually have the data from the database. (jus a small remark that might be of use for somebody)